Class level @Validated is not validating @Size on path variables of an api requests after migrating from springboot 2.7.X to 3.3.1
I have migrated my spring-boot application from 2.7.0 to 3.3.1. In old version, @Size(min = 64, max = 64) is being validated just by having @Validated at class level and throws size must be between 64 and 64. After upgradation to 3.3.1, api requests are not being validated at method level and passing through to service layer/ service implementation layer.
#spring-boot
With SpringBoot 2.7.X it was OK.Below configuration are avilable in my application with SpringBoot 3.3.1

@Validated annotation added on top of the controller class.
Spring-boot-starter-validation-3.3.1 is available


Because that has changed, remove the @Validated that isn't needed anymore. This has been in the Spring upgrade notes (which I suggest to read when doing updates).

Also make sure you aren't messing around with different validation-api classes (the fact that you have the starter doesn't mean you haven't included anything else).

Thanks for the details.Fixed the issue by moving the package from javax.* to jakarta.* .Forgot to update the package name and after moving to new package, its working as expected.

If you can still reference javax.validation classes this also means you have the old API on your classpath. Remove that, all dependencies are already included in the spring-boot-starter-validation dependency.

Yes, removed all the other validation-api dependencies and i can see now it's explicitly giving import issue where missed to rename the package jakarta.Thanks!

Which is a different question. Which doesn't belong in comments but rather another question (or use the search to see if there are others with this problem).
